# Does a nested matrix have any mathematical meaning?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Say A and B are two 2x2 matrices, and C is defined below.
$$ C=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B\\
    B & A
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Is this nonsensical or does it have a meaning? If we're talking about nested determinants, it makes sense. I was wondering if nested matrices are gibberish or have any mathematical meaning.

Comment: what do you mean by "does it have a meaning" ?

Comment: This is a block matrix. Block matrices can be multiplied analogue to the usual procedure assuming the blocks have a suitable size.

Comment: One _can_ talk of matrices whose elements are matrices, but in the vast majority of cases, this notation means a 4×4 [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).

Comment: @Troposphere: the space of "nested matrices" $M_{2\times2}(M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F}))$ is isomorphic as an $\mathbb{F}$-algebra to the space of block matrices $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{F})$.  So those two different notations are the same thing!

Comment: @JacobManaker: I agree, as far as the $\mathbb F$-algebra structure is concerned. But since the OP was talking about determinants, it's important to know that the isomorphism doesn't extend to _determinants_ -- the determinant of the 4×4 matrix $C$ in the question is not the same as (the determinant of) $A^2-B^2$.